# Forward declaration of template friend function

Tags: c++, templates, friend

Consider the following code snippet that works perfectly fine:

```
class A
{
private:
    int d;
public:
    A(int n){ d = n;}
    friend int foo(A a);
};

int foo(A a)
{
    return a.d;
}
```

However, when I try to use a template for the class, I need to forward declare the friend function for it to run, as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class B;

template <typename T>
T foof(B<T> a);


template <typename T>
class B
{
private:
    T d;
public:
    B(T n){ d = n;}
    friend T foof<>(B<T> a);
};

template <typename T>
T foof(B<T> a)
{
    return a.d;
}
```

Why is the forward declaration necessary in the second example but not on the first one? Also, why do I have to put `<>` in the declaration of foof inside class B? Why isn't it enough that it is declared inside of the template? I am trying to understand how these things work so that I don't have to blindly memorize this kind of code when I need to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because

```
friend int foo(A a);
```

is declaration of function and a friend at the same time, but:

```
friend T foof<>(B<T> a);
```

Is friend declaration to template instantiation. That's different. Instantiation doesn't declare template function.

---

You could befriend whole function template, and then forward declaration isn't needed:

```
template <typename T>
class B
{
private:
    T d;
public:
    B(T n){ d = n;}
    template<class U>
    friend U foof(B<U> a);
};
```

Comment: Note: the latter has potentially unintended consequences. It says that, for any given `T`, we're friending *all* instantiations of `foof`, whether or not `T` is the template argument. In short, `int foof<int>(B<int>);` is a friend of `B<double>`. Consider whether that is a problem before taking the scorched-earth approach of blanket-friending all instantiations of a template function (or class).

Answer (score 4):

> Why is the forward declaration necessary in the second example but not on the first one?

Because syntactically the second isn't a form that can be used to declare a function, but the first one is.

> Also, why do I have to put <> in the declaration of foof inside class B? Why isn't it enough that it is declared inside of the template?

You're indicating that you're friending a specialization of a function template, as opposed to friending a function that is NOT a template, which is what it would mean otherwise. You can have non-template friend functions of class templates.